# Unknown "profiler_dump" function

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a Symfony 2.8 app that works on a test system. When I try to deploy it to a live system, however, I find that the pages all return 500 errors, and the app logs the following to a production log:

> [2018-04-17 17:24:29] assetic.ERROR: The template
>   "DoctrineBundle:Collector:db.html.twig" contains an error: Unknown
>   "profiler_dump" function in "DoctrineBundle:Collector:db.html.twig" at
>   line 241. [] []

That twig file is in a vendor subdirectory, so I know that I didn't cause this. It also means that others have likely had this problem before.

Is there a well-known fix for this problem?

Comment: Did you clear your application cache?

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I did indeed clear the cache.